# Поиск по в базе

Tags: база-данных, php, запрос, mysql

В таблице `hashtags` содержатся слова `bla,bla2,bla3`

```
"SELECT * FROM data WHERE hashtags = '$tag' ORDER BY id DESC"
```

не выводит ничего, так как ищет полнострочно. Как правильно запрос сформировать и что еще для этого нужно?

Comment: и еще, в php не пишите переменные внутри кавычек, это уменьшает читабельность и скорость выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, `hashtags` - это поле (столбец)).  Если правильно понял, то вот решение:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `hashtags` like '%".$tag."%' ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример, `hashtags` - столбец. Для данной задачи используются алгоритмы полнотекстового поиска. В худшем случае можно искать по `SELECT * FROM data WHERE hashtags LIKE "' . $tag . '%" ORDER BY id DESC`. Ни в коем случае нельзя использовать `like '%".$tag."%'` , это очень тяжеловесный запрос, т.к. индексы использоваться не будут.

Comment: Но почему нивкоем случае, в многих исходниках хороших движков, такое детище используется, насчет оптимизации... Это играет только для жирных таблиц ;-)

Comment: в хороших движках такой подход не используется